# Saving OnetoOne field manually in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have following models:

```
class Person(User):
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('last name'), max_length=30)

class Service(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='services')
    price_from = models.DecimalField(_('price form'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))])
    price_to = models.DecimalField(_('price to'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))])

class WorkPlace(models.Model):
    service = models.OneToOneField('Service', related_name='work_place', primary_key=True)
    city = CharField(verbose_name=_('city'), max_length=255)
    street = CharField(verbose_name=_('street'), max_length=255)
```

I also registered `Person` in admin and made `Service` an inline admin.
Due to design, city and address are entered as multivalue field.
The problem is that I can't save WorkPlace manually.
Here are the forms:

```
class WorkPlaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkPlace
        fields = '__all__'

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Service

    multi_work_place = MyMultiValueField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        service = super(ServiceForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        if self.cleaned_data['multi_work_place']:
            work_place = WorkPlace(**{
                'city': self.cleaned_data['multi_work_place'][0],
                'street': self.cleaned_data['multi_work_place'][1],
            })
            # when there is brand new object is created, there is no service.pk
            work_place.service = service # how???
            work_place.save()
        return service
```

Moreover, if I write `service = super(ServiceForm, self).save(commit=True)` on new object, this will raise Error as there is no `Person` created.

How can I solve this problem? Recall, that I'm working in admin.

Comment: This code should already work, since `service` is the Service object returned from the super class save. Exactly what happens when you try?

Comment: "person_id column can't be null", if I use service = super(ServiceForm, self).save(commit=True), since really, there is no member yet. How in general Django does such things. If I use service = super(ServiceForm, self).save(commit=commit), then in debugger it appears that commit is False and service is not saved which causes work_place.save() to raise "service_id column can not be null"

Comment: But person_id is a completely separate relationship, so that error has nothing to do with setting the service/workplace one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Service

    multi_work_place = MyMultiValueField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        service = super(ServiceForm, self).save(commit=False)
        service.member_id = service.member.pk # here is the key command
        service.save()
        if self.cleaned_data['multi_work_place']:
            work_place = WorkPlace(**{
                'city': self.cleaned_data['multi_work_place'][0],
                'street': self.cleaned_data['multi_work_place'][1],
            })
            # when there is brand new object is created, there is no service.pk
            work_place.service = service # how???
            work_place.save()
        return service
```

I just needed to add member pk to service model

Comment: and `service.save()` my solution assumed you were passing the correct assignemnt of the member_id in the form data.

Comment: That was the problem. So this could not be an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Service

    multi_work_place = MyMultiValueField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        service = save_instance(self, self.instance, self._meta.fields,
                             fail_message, commit, self._meta.exclude,
                             construct=False)
        service.save()
        if self.cleaned_data['multi_work_place']:
            work_place = WorkPlace(**{
                'city': self.cleaned_data['multi_work_place'][0],
                'street': self.cleaned_data['multi_work_place'][1],
            })
            # when there is brand new object is created, there is no service.pk
            work_place.service = service 
            work_place.save()
        return service
```

Comment: save_instance is not a method of ServiceForm

Comment: you need `form django.forms import save_instance`

Comment: in your current code you maybe able to call the Super function as you have, then just do `service.save()` before using it. i've not tried that route before; save_instance is what the `def save(..)` normally does, i just copied it from there.